# Invalid column name?

Tags: sql, error-handling

What is the problem?

`SELECT distinct a.number,a.code,a.day - (b.Miktar - b.GonderilenMiktar) AS sonuc
FROM dbo.T07  a, T05  b WHERE a.number=b.number and a.code=b.code
and sonuc!=-1`

error:

Invalid column name 'sonuc'.

Comment: use `subQuery` for accessing `sonuc`

Answer (score 1):

can you modify it

```
 SELECT distinct a.number,a.code,a.day - (b.Miktar - b.GonderilenMiktar) AS sonuc
 from dbo.T07 a join
       T05 b 
       on a.number = b.number and a.code = b.code
 where (b.Miktar - b.GonderilenMiktar)!= -1
```

Comment: Thank You very Much

Answer (score 0):

A column alias cannot be used in the same `select` or `where` or other clauses.  You need a CTE or subquery:

```
select distinct number, code, sonuc
from (select a.number, a.code,
             a.day - (b.Miktar - b.GonderilenMiktar) as sonuc
      from dbo.T07 a join
           T05 b 
           on a.number = b.number and a.code = b.code
     ) ab
where sonuc <> -1;
```

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.
- The standard SQL operator for not equals is `<>`.

Comment: I can't understand why should we nest query? actually, it would be nice if you explain about any other performance related concerns related to this.

Comment: Thank you veru much